# AWS DataExchange API fetch returning response '404: Asset not found'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql

I'm trying to fetch data from an AWS DataExchange provider based on their company's API specification.

I'm using the AWS Node.JS NPM modules 'aws-sdk' and '@aws-sdk/client-dataexchange'.

However, every query I've written is returning the error '404: Asset not found'.

I'm subscribed to use the API and I've verified that all my AWS credentials, policies and IAM keys give me permission to access the API.

Could someone please help me identify what's wrong with my query in relation to the API specification.

Thanks!

The response I get looks like below:

```
404: Asset not found

  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 404,
    requestId: 'b7e6e691-xxxxxxx7657201138a4',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: 'dBQBwlCE8cXp4--xxxxxxxxxxx3j2lTfxywUezCPEA6nusJCJg==',
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  ResourceType: 'ASSET',
  ResourceId: 'e055c882bde1fa3xxxxxxxxx'
}
```

My current request 'body' looks like below:

```js
Body: JSON.stringify({
  "description": "GraphQL query for the Ursa Space Imagery Catalog.",
  "content": {
    "application/graphql": {
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchRequest"
        },
        "query": {
          "description": "Limit the number of records in a response.",
          "value":"{\n  availablemetadatarecord(\n    limit: 20\n    content: { catalogProperties: { vendor: { eq: \"ICEYE\" } } }\n  ) {\n    assignedId\n  }\n}\n"
          }
          }
          },
          "required": true
          }),
```

The DataExchange provider's actual API specification looks like below:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "image-services",
    "description": "API Gateway for integration of Platform Services into AWS Data Exchange",
    "version": "2022-03-03T20:04:18Z"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": ""
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/psdm/graphql": {
      "post": {
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "GraphQL query for the Catalog in the form of:\n\n  `{\n    availablemetadatarecord(\n      QUERYPARAMS\n    ) { \n      FIELDLIST\n    } \n  }`\n",
          "content": {
            "application/graphql": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchRequest"
              },
              "examples": {
                "Limit returned data": {
                  "description": "Limit the number of records in a response.\n\nIn your query, simply specify `limit: <int>` \n",
                  "value": "{\n  availablemetadatarecord(\n    limit: 10\n    content: { catalogProperties: { vendor: { eq: \"EYE\" } } }\n  ) {\n    assignedId\n  }\n}\n"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "sigv4": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "CatalogSearchRequest": {
        "title": "CatalogSearchRequest",
        "type": "object"
      },
      "CatalogSearchResponse": {
        "title": "Catalog Search Response",
        "required": [
          "data",
          "paginationInfo"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "paginationInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "recordsInPage": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "nextOffset": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "availablemetadatarecord": {
                "type": "array",
                "description": "Records returned by query",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "sigv4": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "awsSigv4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the graphql url you are pointing at?

Comment: The link says missing authentication token. https://api-fulfill.dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/psdm/graphql